# How to read and write a byte from and to stdin/stdout using Syscall in x86 with NASM assembler?

Tags: io, x86, nasm, system-calls, cdecl

I am trying to read a string from stdin and print it back out using x86, NASM, and Syscalls. Reading in a byte will be a function, and writing out a byte will be a function. I am reading the string from stdin and putting each char into an array. Here is my initial idea:

```
;read_writer.asm
section .data
    arr times 100 db 0   ; array of 100 elements initialzed to 0
    ptr dd 0

section .text
global _start
_start:
    push ebp   ; setup stack
    mov ebp, esp   ; setup stack
    push, 0x10   ; allocate space for potential local variables
    call readin: ;call read in func
    push eax  ;return char from readin will be in eax, push it for writeout 
    call writeout:
    leave 
    mov eax, 1 ;exit
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

readin:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp ; setup stack

   mov eax, 3 ;read
   mov ebx, 1 ;stdin
              ; i feel like i am missing code here bit not sure what

   leave  ;reset stack
   ret ;return eax

writeout:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp ; setup stack
   push eax   ;push eax since it was pushed earlier
   mov eax, 4 ;write
   mov ebx, 1 ;stdout
              ; i feel like i am missing code here bit not sure what

   leave  ;reset stack
   ret ;return eax
```

Sample input:

```
Hello World
```

Sample output:

```
Hello World
```

The functions should be used with cdecl, which I dont think I am doing correctly. I also realised I am not putting the chars into arr.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you're missing the `int 0x80` in both `readin` and `writeout`.

And, as you can see [here](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html), both `sys_read` and `sys_write` expect a `(const) char*` in `ecx`. That address should point to the buffer where the bytes to write are stored / the read bytes should be stored.
The value of `edx` should be set to the number of bytes to read / write.

So in the `readin` example you want something like:

```
mov eax, 3    ;read
mov ebx, 0    ;stdin. NOTE: stdin is 0, not 1
sub esp,4     ; Allocate some space on the stack
mov ecx,esp   ; Read characters to the stack
mov edx,1
int 0x80
movzx eax,byte [esp]  ; Place the character in eax, which is used for function return values
add esp,4
```

And similarly for `writeout`.

Comment: By placing the address of the array in `ecx` prior to the system call.

Comment: would this place each char in a different indice?

Comment: If you read multiple characters with the same system call, yes. Otherwise, no, not automatically.